# Where is MaxItemCount for cosmos DB pagination for Python azure SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-python-sdk

having searching quite while and haven't found the **MaxItemCount** for cosmos DB pagination in python azure SDK  from the [official web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-pagination) and the [code sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/examples.py#L89)

The REST-api is written by FastAPI framework, use Azure cosmos DB as the storage, pagination hasn't been implemented. The cosmos sdk I'm using is version 3.1.2

```
query = {"query": "SELECT * FROM aac104 ORDER BY aac104.entryTimestamp ASC"}                    
for item_dict in client.QueryItems(self.clink, query, options={"enableCrossPartitionQuery": True}):   
    yield self._parse_entry(item_dict)
```

Can someone help me with how to use **MaxItemCount** to get the pagination function on in Python Azure SDK?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Comment: @GauravMantri added

Comment: What version of Python Cosmos DB SDK you're using? It doesn't look like the latest version (4.2.0).

Comment: yes you are right, azure-cosmos 3.1.2 is the  version I'm using

Comment: @GauravMantri You mean I can only use `MaxItemCount` for pagination in the later versioned SDK?

Comment: `You mean I can only use MaxItemCount for pagination in the later versioned SDK?` - That should not be the case though it is recommended that you use the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SDK version 3.x (that you're using), please try by definining `maxItemCount` in the query options. Your code would be something like:

```
query = {"query": "SELECT * FROM aac104 ORDER BY aac104.entryTimestamp ASC"}                    
for item_dict in client.QueryItems(self.clink, query, options={"enableCrossPartitionQuery": True; "maxItemCount": 10;}):   
    yield self._parse_entry(item_dict)
```